# Abel 's partial summation formula and inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have a problem from a paper.

> Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be a sequence of positive real number. If $b_n\geq b_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $$\sum_{k=j}^n a_kb_k\leq (\sup_{m\in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^m a_k)(jb_j +b_{j+1}+\dots + b_n)$$

The hint of proof is using Abel 's partial summation formula. I have no idea to prove that statement.

Comment: Let $S := \sup\limits_{m} \frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m a_k.$ If $S = +\infty$ you're done. Otherwise, let $A_n = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n a_k$. Write $a_k = A_k - A_{k-1}$ and use $A_n \leqslant n\cdot S$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion @Daniel Fischer